# Error: "cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress" only when running from pytest/TestClient

Tags: python, postgresql, python-asyncio, fastapi, asyncpg

This is coming up while trying to run unit tests on a simple FastAPI application using asyncpg. Minimal reproducer:

```
import asyncpg


class Database:
    def __init__(self, dsn):
        self.dsn = dsn
        self.pool = None

    # creates connection pool
    async def connect(self):
        if not self.pool:
            self.pool = await asyncpg.create_pool(
                min_size=1,
                max_size=200,
                max_inactive_connection_lifetime=10
                command_timeout=60,
                dsn=self.dsn
            )

    async def fetch(self, query: str, *args):
        if not self.pool:
            await self.connect()

        async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:
            prep_stmt = await conn.prepare(query)
            result = await prep_stmt.fetch(*args)

        return result

    async def close(self):
        if self.pool:
            await self.pool.close()
```

Here's the app:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, status

from app.database import Database

app = FastAPI(title="simple app")
db = Database("postgresql://postgres:postgres@10.201.0.110/postgres")


@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    await db.connect()


@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown_event():
    await db.close()


@app.get("/test")
async def get_test():

    try:
        result = await db.fetch("SELECT 1 as foo")
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
                            detail=f"Got exception: {e}")

    return result
```

Now this works perfectly when tested from the command line, eg:

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/test && echo && curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/test && echo 
[{"foo":1}]
[{"foo":1}]
```

but the second request fails when the call is made using TestClient inside pytest:

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

from app.app import app

client = TestClient(app)


def test_get():

    response = client.get("/test")
    print(response.content)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    response = client.get("/test")
    print(response.content)
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

here's the output:

```
$ pytest -v -s tests/
======================================================= test session starts =======================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.10.11, pytest-7.3.1, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /usr/local/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /tmp/myapp
plugins: anyio-3.7.0
collected 1 item                                                                                                                  

tests/test_api.py::test_get b'[{"foo":1}]'
b'{"detail":"Got exception: cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress"}'
FAILED

============================================================ FAILURES =============================================================
____________________________________________________________ test_get _____________________________________________________________

    def test_get():
    
        response = client.get("/test")
        print(response.content)
        assert response.status_code == 200
        response = client.get("/test")
        print(response.content)
>       assert response.status_code == 200
E       assert 500 == 200
E        +  where 500 = <Response [500 Internal Server Error]>.status_code

tests/test_api.py:15: AssertionError
===================================================== short test summary info =====================================================
FAILED tests/test_api.py::test_get - assert 500 == 200
======================================================== 1 failed in 0.28s ========================================================
Future exception was never retrieved
future: <Future finished exception=ConnectionDoesNotExistError('connection was closed in the middle of operation')>
asyncpg.exceptions.ConnectionDoesNotExistError: connection was closed in the middle of operation
```

I can't figure out why, only with pytest/TestClient, I'm getting that `cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress` response for the second request.

EDIT: turns out this is not related to pytest, only to the usage of `TestClient`. The following code is already enough to trigger the problem:

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient

from app.app import app

client = TestClient(app)

response = client.get("/test")
print(response.status_code, response.content)
response = client.get("/test")
print(response.status_code, response.content)
```

EDIT 2: To see the full traceback, I just re-raised the exception in the app and I get this for the second - failing - request:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/myapp/app/database.py", line 27, in fetch
    prep_stmt = await conn.prepare(query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 565, in prepare
    return await self._prepare(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 583, in _prepare
    stmt = await self._get_statement(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 397, in _get_statement
    statement = await self._protocol.prepare(
  File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 156, in prepare
  File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 741, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.BaseProtocol._new_waiter
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 721, in call_later
    timer = self.call_at(self.time() + delay, callback, *args,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 732, in call_at
    self._check_closed()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 515, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/myapp/simpletest.py", line 9, in <module>
    response = client.get("/test")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/testclient.py", line 499, in get
    return super().get(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1041, in get
    return self.request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/testclient.py", line 465, in request
    return super().request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 814, in request
    return self.send(request, auth=auth, follow_redirects=follow_redirects)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 901, in send
    response = self._send_handling_auth(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 929, in _send_handling_auth
    response = self._send_handling_redirects(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 966, in _send_handling_redirects
    response = self._send_single_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httpx/_client.py", line 1002, in _send_single_request
    response = transport.handle_request(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/testclient.py", line 342, in handle_request
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/testclient.py", line 339, in handle_request
    portal.call(self.app, scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/from_thread.py", line 277, in call
    return cast(T_Retval, self.start_task_soon(func, *args).result())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 458, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 403, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/anyio/from_thread.py", line 217, in _call_func
    retval = await retval
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 276, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 21, in __call__
    raise e
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/middleware/asyncexitstack.py", line 18, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 718, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 237, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/fastapi/routing.py", line 163, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "/tmp/myapp/app/app.py", line 27, in get_test
    result = await db.fetch("SELECT 1 as foo")
  File "/tmp/myapp/app/database.py", line 26, in fetch
    async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 220, in release
    raise ex
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncpg/pool.py", line 210, in release
    await self._con.reset(timeout=budget)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 1366, in reset
    await self.execute(reset_query, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/asyncpg/connection.py", line 317, in execute
    return await self._protocol.query(query, timeout)
  File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 323, in query
  File "asyncpg/protocol/protocol.pyx", line 707, in asyncpg.protocol.protocol.BaseProtocol._check_state
asyncpg.exceptions._base.InterfaceError: cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress
```

So it looks like the real problem is that `Event loop is closed` error.

EDIT 3: Restructuring the testing code as follows works fine:

```
with TestClient(app) as client:
    response = client.get("/test")
    print(response.status_code, response.content)

    response = client.get("/test")
    print(response.status_code, response.content)
```

Still not sure where the original problem is, but at least now I have a workaround.

According to [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/testing-events/), using `TestClient` as a context manager invokes the startup and shutdown events; that seems to be the only difference. I'm still unclear why it does not work in the "normal" (ie non context-manager) mode, as the function `Database.fetch()` creates the pool anyway if it does not exist, so in principle there should be no practical difference compared to really executing the startup `db.connect()` event. Obviously, that is not true, otherwise I wouldn't be seeing the error.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the
[MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example),
that's very nice.

---

What's different between pytest and the curls?

Well, pytest has a `requests` web client pool,
so it can hold a TCP connection open and reuse it
on the second request.
In contrast each curl runs in a separate child process,
so we're clearly tearing down the old TCP connection
and creating a brand new one.

---

Instead of

```
        async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:
```

I think you want this:

```
        async with self.pool.acquire() as conn:
            async with conn.transaction():
```

This should have two beneficial results:

- finish the transaction so next request goes into a new transaction
- release reader locks on the table(s) your SELECT just read from

Lingering reader locks become very noticeable when for example
a DBA wants to DROP or ALTER TABLE, since an exclusive lock is not compatible with a reader lock.

---

When assigning the prepared statement,
it looks like you have an opportunity to
[cache](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)
such queries. Your real app probably only
has a handful of distinct queries,
and then WHERE clause filters get
substituted in via a `params` argument.
(Hopefully there's no `f" WHERE x = {x}"`
string interpolation, which would open
the door to possible
[injection](https://xkcd.com/327) attacks.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't the connection release performed implicitly since it's being used inside the context manager?

Comment: Added the transaction context, same failure.

Comment: And in any case, I also tried to `client.close()` + `client = TestClient(app)` between the two requests, which I understand should forcibly close any outstanding TCP connection, and I got the same result.